# Sagemath: Is there a way to print out all the elements of a Group or a Ring?

Tags: python, sage

How do I print out all the elements of a Group or Ring in Sagemath?

I am unable to find any command/function in the docs which do this. So I tried through a Python for & I am unable to understand the output

I tried this with a field

```
sage: A = GF(7)
sage: [print(i) for i in A]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I am unable to figure out what is the None, None, None ... at the end.

Unable also to understand the output of a Quotient ring

```
 R.<x> = PolynomialRing(Integers(7))
 A = R.quotient(x^2)
 [print(i) for i in A]

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
xbar
xbar + 1
...
xbar + 6
2*xbar
...
2*xbar + 6
...
3*xbar + 6
...
6*xbar + 6
[None,
...
None]
```

Here again, what is the xbar & what are the nones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `print` prints its argument and returns `None`,
which is the closest in Python to "not returning anything".

When the return value of a command is `None`, it does not
get displayed. Here however you are building a list
of these return values, so you get a list all of whose
elements are `None`, and that list does get displayed.

To avoid that, use a for loop without building a list.

```
sage: A = GF(7)
sage: for i in A:
....:     print(i)
....:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Starting from a polynomial ring with variable `x`,
and taking a quotient, Sage uses `xbar` as the
default name for the image of the variable `x`
in the quotient.

To choose a different name:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(Zmod(3))
sage: A.<t> = R.quotient(x^2)
sage: for i in A:
....:     print(i)
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(Integers(3))
sage: A.<t> = R.quotient(x^2)
sage: for i in A:
....:     print(i)
....:
0
1
2
t
t + 1
t + 2
2*t
2*t + 1
2*t + 2
```

One can also use `x` for the variable name in the quotient:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(Zmod(3))
sage: A.<x> = R.quotient(x^2)
sage: for i in A:
....:     print(i)
....:
0
1
2
x
x + 1
x + 2
2*x
2*x + 1
2*x + 2
```

If you want a one-liner rather than a full-blown print loop,
you can use `consume` from the more_itertools package
(which you first have to install using pip).

```
sage: %pip install more_itertools
...
sage: from more_itertools import consume
sage: consume(print(i) for i in A)
0
1
2
x
x + 1
x + 2
2*x
2*x + 1
2*x + 2
```